# How to add more editors

Tags: modeling

So I opened blender and to my supprise certain windows are missing as seen bellow
[image]

I want the default editors that come with new blender files. How would one go about adding them back in, I need it arranged like when you open a new blender file like this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, when a window shows 'Back to Previous', it means that you can press ctrl-up arrow and return to the non-focused layout. This view has been focused on the current active window with the ctrl-up arrow.

If you open a new file and it doesn't have the layouts liek you are used to using, sometimes you can get them back by reopening the file with 'Load UI' unchecked.

Comment: The control up arrow worked, what is a focused layout and is there a guide that can explain layouts, views, and editors that you would recommend that I can use as a reference for later. While I can model I know little about views, layouts, and editor windows and settings.

Comment: Zacharias Reinhardt has a very good overview video on working with the ui https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OF8d4wz0t0Q

Comment: Here is the main explanation for what I think you are asking about https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a case of accidentally pressing shift+space. If you point at any window (3D view, properties, etc) and press shift+space it will maximise that window.

To return, you can simply press shift+space again or--as mentioned above--press ctrl+up arrow.

Comment: Or `Ctrl`+`space` for maximize depending on your Blender version.