# How to add viewport

Tags: 3d-view

I got a new laptop the Microsoft Surfacebook 2 and now when using blender there aren't the little plus boxes in the corners of my viewports to allow me to add more viewports. Anyone know why this is or how to add more viewports?

Comment: They are still there, just invisible, try it in the corner

Comment: Perhaps you have enabled Full Screen by pressing Shft+Space

Comment: Possible dupliate of  [how to add more editors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88170/how-to-add-more-editors/88194#88194) or [Accidentally hit “toggle full screen”, How do I exit?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55992/accidentally-hit-toggle-full-screen-how-do-i-exit/55994#55994)