# How to access Viewport Properties dialog with small viewport (3d view)?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, accessibility

When I have multiple viewports and I want to change Viewport Properties for a single small viewport, I would normally access "Viewport Properties" pull-down in the upper right corner of the viewport. However, with Blender 2.90 those buttons are not visible when viewport is "too narrow". Is it possible to open that dialog some other way?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/132667/3413

Comment: Workaround: toggle viewport maximized, access the normal dropdown menu in top right corner and toggle viewport maximized again. Note that to maximize the correct viewport, you have to hover the mouse cursor above the viewport you want to configure and press `CTRL`+`space`. For more details, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55995/3413

Comment: Assuming it's the same as 2.8, hold the mousewheel button down when over the menu bar and drag it to the left.

Comment: @JohnEason: thanks, it seems to work. Technically holding the mousewheel button down is same as holding middle mouse button. Most modern mouses do not have separate middle mouse button from pressing the wheel down. However, some mice have programmable extra buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**All menu bars and panels everywhere in Blender can be scrolled by holding middle mouse button down over the area you want to scroll.** Most modern mice have middle button integrated with the mouse wheel so in practice you hover the mouse over the bar that you want to scroll (in the above image the bar with words "View Select Add Object"), press and hold mouse wheel down and move mouse towards left and you can access the end of that bar. The same method works for accessing e.g. all the tabs or tab contents in "too short" Properties Editor.

As far as I know, there's no keyboard accessible way to do this. And it doesn't seem to work with menus because menus have small visible arrows at the top and at the bottom if a menu cannot fit within Blender window.

Thanks to @JohnEason for tip!